# SFML is giving me unknown symbols on mac

Tags: c++, gcc, symbols, sfml

I compiled SFML2 using the instructions to get it working with C++11 on mac, by adding the flag in cmake.

Whenever I try the libraries, using Eclipse as my IDE, I get unknown symbols, the command it is using is as follows:

```
g++-4.7 -L/usr/local/lib -std=c++11 -o "Breakout"  ./main.o   -lsfml-window -lsfml-system -lsfml-graphics
```

The error it spits out is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"sf::RenderWindow::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, sf::ContextSettings const&)", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
```

Using this code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main () {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800,600), "window");
    return 1;
}
```

The problem, I think, might be that SFML is compiled with Clang, and I am using GCC 4.7. I am unable to compile SFML using GCC, because it complains about Objective C and Cocoa stuff. If I can avoid it, I don't want to change over to Clang for this project, as I like Eclipse for an IDE, but Clang support is crap.

EDIT: I almost forgot, everything works fine on Linux. I have a project that I am porting, and I was trying to make a breakout clone to test things out. The project that I already have is quite large, and I want to avoid as much work as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution. If I use the precompiled libs from the SFML website, it compiles fine. My question now, is why? They act the same, and I presume the were compiled using the same methods.

Answer (score 0):

To compile SFML with C++11 support you need two tools (as explained in the getting started tutorial) : clang *with* libc++.

Libc++ and libstdc++ have two different implementations of the S(T)L. That's the issue here.

Unfortunately there is no magic solution; you'll have either to use SFML without C++11 or get SFML compiled with g++ 4.7 and C++11 support. Or you can use another IDE, of course.

Please note that SFML won't officially support non official compilers. However, you're welcome to give it a try and share your experience on the official forum.